# In Figma: How to specify layouts for CSS grid systems?

Tags: css-grid, figma

Summary: I have seemingly hit a limitation in Figma when trying to make the columns behave akin to a CSS grid system. I would like to know if I have misunderstood Figma's built in capabilities, if there is a plug-in that solves the problem, if I have to create one Figma frame per CSS breakpoint (undesirable), or if there are other solutions.

Background: As an interaction/ UX designer, I would like to specify the responsiveness of a web based application, so that the front end developers know how the interface should appear at all browser widths. They implement in a CSS-based grid system similar to [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/)

So far, I failed in achieving what I want, and the most knowledgeable UX'ers in the company think I have hit a limitation in Figma's capabilities, but they are not certain.

Basically, what I want is [this basic responsiveness](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pcm7646072frv2y/responsive-layout-basic-test.mov?dl=0), but column based. But as shown [in this video, none of my experiments work](https://www.dropbox.com/s/04wkrcpipsw715l/figma-grid-system-test.mov?dl=0).

I wonder if it boils down to this: If a Figma child element has:

- horisontal constraint set to “Scale” and
- vertical constraint set to “Hug contents”

Then the parent element cannot have:

- vertical constraint set to “Hug contents”

Is this is a known limitation in Figma? If yes, are there plugins that solve this problem, or is it outside Figma's scope to offer this type of alignment with CSS-based grid systems? Obviously, it would be very beneficial if the solution also supports [breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/breakpoints/).

P.S. I [have asked](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9343/232337) which SE site that was most suitable for this question, and SO was the [suggested site](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9344/232337). The question was closed on [UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/142469/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, according to [an answer on Figma's own forum](https://forum.figma.com/t/is-it-not-possible-to-use-the-columns-as-a-css-style-grid-system/13191/3), Figma's columns cannot behave akin to a CSS grid system, even though *“several threads [have] requested [this] evolution”*.